# SDL Tridion-related Open Source Projects

Tags: discussion

[Google tells me we have several repositories](https://www.google.com/search?q=tridion%20open%20source%20project) on Google Code and GitHub, but it's hard to get context on what's active. **What projects can SDL Tridion technical community members participate in?**

Please add (one answer per repository) your favorite SDL Tridion-related open source repositories with maybe an introduction and how to get started.

*See PowerTools as an example below.*

Comment: With [Google Code shutting down](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html), a few of these will likely move to GitHub or another repository. Feel free to post updates below if you have plans to move. Thanks @PeterK for getting started with [PowerTools, now on GitHub](https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-powertools).

Answer (score 6):

The [SDL Tridion World project on Google code](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/) is simply a code hosting project for our open source eXtensions on [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/index.aspx) which are generally licensed under the Reciprocal Public License 1.5 (RPL1.5).

In the project you will find the source code for eXtensions for SDL Tridion (versions 2011 and 2013 currently) so that everybody can use, and help to further develop them.

### Current contents

- ItemSelector - Custom URL for selecting an item URI from a SDL Tridion tree view
- XHTMLtoBBCode - DWT Template function source for converting RTF XHTML into BBCode
- FlickrEclProvider - Example ECL Provider making photos from a configured Flickr photostream available directly inside SDL Tridion
- EclTbb - Example ECL Template Building Blocks
- EclImport - 2013 UI extension which adds import capabilities for ECL items
- A few undocumented repositories

If anybody wants access to add or maintain code in there feel free to contact me through the project.

Answer (score 5):

"Tridion practice" is known mostly for the Tridion cookbook, but there's also some useful code there. (The license is MIT, which might be more suitable for people who find RPL to be too restrictive for practical use.)

https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki

Answer (score 4):

The PowerTools are a "wide range of tools developed to speed up content management processes within SDL Tridion, specifically helpful for powerusers with administrator tasks."

[SDL Tridion Powertools for R5 through 2009 is on SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx). It's no longer active, but I've heard a few of the tools work in 2011 if you navigate directly to individual tools. Several of the original developers are Tridion Stack Exchange users. :-)

[SDL Tridion Powertools for 2011 (and 2013) is <strike>on Google Code</strike>](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/) now on [GitHub](https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-powertools). Details and announcements are on the site, but we're always looking for:

- Developers and non-technical contributors (requirements, project management, QA, etc.)
- Ideas, requests, and feedback
- [Bug reports](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/issues/list) :-)

Follow the [links in the bottom left of the site](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/) to collaborate or join the discussion. Or [get latest to check out the code directly](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/checkout).

Answer (score 3):

[Search Integration 4 Tridion](http://si4t.github.io/) (SI4T)

A framework for integrating any delivery side search engine. Consists of:

- .NET TBBs to generate indexing directives when publishing content
- Generic Storage Extension to process indexing directives and hand-off to a search-engine specific indexer
- Indexer implementation for Apache Solr
- NuGet packages for example integration with ASP.NET MVC project

Coming soon:

- Indexer implementation to place XML files on filesystem to be 'crawled' by search engine

There is also a whole [backlog](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/wiki/Backlog) of stuff which needs work on

Answer (score 2):

The T-Cubed testing framework

https://github.com/DominicCronin/T-cubed

Comment: Thanks, Dominic. Was this the same setup you presented at Tridion Developer Summit?

Comment: Yes - I gave a short demo, but there's more to the framework than that.

Answer (score 2):

[DD4T MarkupModels](https://github.com/buildingblocks/BuildingBlocks.DD4T.MarkupModels)

Aims to simplify mapping Schemas to ViewModels in DD4T aiming for Domain Driven Design and for an improved development experience with the benefit of strongly typed Views.

Provides attributes for most types of schema fields and automates some common operations such as parsing Rich Text and resolving Component Links.

Also provides helpers for Experience Manager integration.

Is still in Beta.

Answer (score 1):

XView, a decoupled Tridion TOM.NET templating framework.

http://xview.codeplex.com

When "Modular Templating" with .NET was first announced I was hoping for something like XView, but it turned out to be a big disappointment. So I decided to create something like XView and called it XView :)

Answer (score 0):

[Configurable Experience Manager Regions](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/SDL-Tridion-Template-Tools/tree/master/Regions)

A setup from Nuno Linhares and Angel Puntero that makes XPM regions configurable.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tridion Kickstart Project](https://github.com/TridionCommunity/kickstart-tridion-environment) creates a diamond BluePrint with example content.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tridion BA Toolkit](https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-ba-toolkit) is a Core Service .NET project that outputs authorization details in .csv format including Publications, Groups, Scope, and Organizational items up to 5 levels deep.